# Aptana crashes out of memory

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Aptana crashes with
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal SIGINT to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the memory adding/modifing

AptanaStudio3.ini

the following lines

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=256m
-XX:MaxNewSize=356m
-XX:PermSize=256m
```